# Facebook and Twitter Connect in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter

I want to connect Facebook and Twitter account with my iOS app. I am looking for the code which checks if accounts is there in settings or not. If it's there it takes for login with same account and if it's not then asks user to add account in settings.

I tried couple of things but really not working. If anyone needs my code, then let me know i will post it on pastebin.

Comment: You can post your relevant code here and state the problem you are facing in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Social Framework to you project and import in your class

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

For Facebook

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller addImage:UIImage];
controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    if(result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

};
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
else
{

 //Show Alert: No Facebook Account in Settings Page

}
```

For Twitter

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [controller addUrl:NSURL];
controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    if(result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

};
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
else
{

 //Show Alert: No Twitter Account in Settings Page

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add Twitter and Social Framework in your Project and import in your class file like

`#import <Social/Social.h>`
`#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>`

`For Facebook`

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

```
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    NSData *aImgdata=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"EditImage"];
    if (aImgdata) {
        UIImage *aImage=[UIImage imageWithData:aImgdata];
        [controller addImage:aImage];
    }

    controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if(result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    };
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
else
{

     [self ShowAlertView: @"You can't share on facebook right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Facebook account setup"];

}
```

`For Twitter`

if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {

```
        {

            TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

            NSData *aImgdata=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"EditImage"];
            if (aImgdata) {
                UIImage *aImage=[UIImage imageWithData:aImgdata];
                [tweetViewController addImage:aImage];
            }

            tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

                    [self ShowAlertView: @"Tweet Has been Shared"];

                }
                [[AppDelegate sharedInstance]showActivity:NO];
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };

            [self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }

    } else {

        [self ShowAlertView: @"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"];
    }
```

Comment: I want to implement it on the toggle buttons, like I have shown a toggle button for Connect with Facebook and Connect with twitter, is it possible to implement it ? If account is there then user is redirected to my facebook app/twitter app with same details.

Answer (score 0):

To check if you can share with Facebook or Twitter, use: 
`[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:serviceType]`
Where serviceType can be any of the SLServiceTypes such as, `SLServiceTypeFacebook` and `SLServiceTypeTwitter`
This will basically check if they have those services natively connected in their settings. I don't think you can ask the user to add it in their settings. Most of the time, a particular sharing option just won't show up if it is not available like on a `UIActionSheet`.

My guess would be that you can use the `SLComposeViewController` to check for a connected account and if not connected, use the appropriate SDK to connect their account with your iOS app.